# GET or POST for record to be updated

Tags: php, post, web-applications, get

In a basic CRUD based PHP web application, functionality is required to update given records in a database on the server. An update page can be called from a list of records and the id of the record to be changed must be passed to this page.

In this situation which of GET or POST would be considered best practice? GET would obviously allow for a user to change the value a lot easier than POST so suitable checks for existance and ownership of the record would be important. On the other hand POST could confuse users on refresh or navigation with the back/forward buttons asking for confirmation of resubmission when they were unaware of any data being submitted.

Comment: If you're updating or inserting in to a database, use POST. If you're selecting (navigation, searching, etc) use GET.

Comment: This is the step before updating a record - it is passing the record id to the form. The form will obviously use post to send the changes to the server, but is post also most suitable for passing the id to the edit form?

Comment: Yes, post should be used for anything relating to update, insert, delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this situation which of GET or POST would be considered best practice?

POST. You are sending data to update the content on the server. That is what POST is for.

> GET would obviously allow for a user to change the value a lot easier than POST

This is the difference between "trivial" and "very trivial". Don't let anything relating to the ability of the user to change the request influence your decision to pick a request method.

> On the other hand POST could confuse users on refresh or navigation with the back/forward buttons asking for confirmation of resubmission

To avoid this, use the [POST/Redirect/GET pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Use a POST request to handle the update. Send a redirect to the browser. Then the browser will GET the page with the updated data.

> when they were unaware of any data being submitted.

It seems an odd use case where you would want the user to update the record without realising it.

Comment: Very helpful - thanks. I'm not wanting a user to update a record without realising though - I'm referring to the passing of an id to to a form which would then allow a user to update the record of the id which was passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want random people changing random values (changing the value in the url) you should use post. As far is I would do it, I would use POST for all database transactions (update, delete) since that is more secure.
Most browsers warn when a post has been done (=resubmitting a form/...).

Answer (score 0):

- You should use $_GET when someone is requesting data from your
  application.
- And you should use $_POST when someone is pushing (inserting or
  updating ; or deleting) data to your application.

You can use $_REQUEST as well as it contains the information about get and post both with $_COOKIES.

But if you are not using cookies so i recommend you to use $_POST not $_COOKIES.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use GET for report and POST for updates.

Use GET when you want users to access some content quickly and keep on mind that the user will can change the parameters manually.

Use POST when you don't want users see or change parameters and alert user on resent form.

You can use POST with a redirection result, it will prevent retransmissions definitely.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a redirection result please?

Comment: The result of POST page is a redirection to another page, I usually use a referer page. Exemple: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']">